`MySqlDataReader.GetGuid` returns incorrect UUID
I generate UUIDs by using UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), true) and storing them as BINARY(16).
However, when fetching the values:
var uuid = dataReader.GetGuid(name);
Console.WriteLine(uuid.ToString());

I do get an uuid string printed, but it is not the same string as when running SELECT BIN_TO_UUID("col") on the column.
What am I doing wrong?

I tried setting OldGuids in connection string to true but still got the same incorrect uuid back.
I am using MySql.Data .NET Connector version 8.3.0. And server is version 8.0.36.
Reason I'm using UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), true) and storing them as BINARY(16) is that, according to my readings, I thought this was the most efficient way to store uuids and using them as primary keys.

Thanks
Additional Info



Operation
Returns




GetGuid(col)
3da4ec11-3568-cfb4-92aa-b42e99eb957f


BIN_TO_UUID(col)
11eca43d-6835-b4cf-92aa-b42e99eb957f


BIN_TO_UUID(col, true)
6835b4cf-a43d-11ec-92aa-b42e99eb957f




If you are converting the value on the way in, I would expect you would need to convert it on the way out. But I don't know anything about mysql and uuids.

what is the difference between these two guids? Can you share values that you think should be the same? Also: BIN_TO_UUID("col") isn't the reverse of how you generated the UUID but that might an oversight.

If you're creating and storing them with UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), true), then you will need to read them back with BIN_TO_UUID(columnName, true).
MySqlDataReader.GetGuid in MySQL Connector/NET (i.e., MySql.Data) has no ability to do this. Some options are:

Change your SQL to use BIN_TO_UUID(columnName, true) everywhere, remove Old Guids=true from your connection string, and use GetGuid to read the string that is returned.
Stop using the true flag when using UUID_TO_BIN to store the GUID (and just use UUID_TO_BIN(UUID())); this will put the bytes in the order that GetGuid expects.
Switch to MySqlConnector and use GuidFormat = TimeSwapBinary16 in your connection string.


Oh, I wasn't aware that I should convert it back using the true flag as well!
Using (1), reading the column as BIN_TO_UUID(columnName, true) and using GetGuid , the returned Guid gets the correct value, e.g., same as SELECT BIN_TO_UUID(columnName, true).
But then I might just use GetString to read it. When using option (2), will GetGuid read the binary data directly?

The reason I was using the true flag is that I read somewhere in the MySql docs that it was more performant (using the MAC address of the server). But I don't know if that still applies now, or if I even understood the docs correctly. I rather just use UUID_TO_BIN(UUID()) if that is as performant. But the database has already been in use for a couple of years so I don't think I can change the uuids now.

UUID_TO_BIN(x, true) can improve performance if the column is indexed, due to how the time-based values are stored. Otherwise, it's not necessary. However, once you start using the , true flag, you should use it consistently to write and read GUIDs from that column so you're guaranteed to get the right values.

Ok, good, because these uuids are primary keys so they're indexed.
Do you know if changing the hardware will affect performance? Since then there will be a different mac address that the uuid is based on.

@Karmeye The MAC address is stored in the last six bytes of a v1 UUID so it would only matter (for the order of UUIDs in an index) if two v1 UUIDs were generated during the same 100-nanosecond interval.

Wow, you are well versed in these matters! So do I understand you correctly that the performance improvements using the true flag only is relevant to generating uuids in succession? So when querying the database, e.g., with SELECT, whether the true flag is used or not does not impact performance?

@Karmeye That's correct. The true flag is used to change the GUIDs so that they're much more likely to be added as new rows at the end of the table, rather than being inserted in the middle of the table, which will have to move the existing data around. The performance of looking up existing data isn't affected by using the true flag or not.

Look-up performance was the sole reason I added the flag. I should've asked here first :) Perhaps I'll convert all the uuids at some point. Thanks!

You need to manually fix the endian issue like this:
var v = dataReader.GetValue(dataReader.GetOrdinal(name));
if(v is byte[] data && data.Length == 16)
    return new Guid(data, bigEndian: true);

The reason for this is that MySQL constructs GUID string in byte by byte order, while .NET converts the first three sections to integer form in default endian. MySqlDataReader.GetGuid doesn't change the endian by default, so it will be LE in general.

This is a great answer but the OP will need to switch from MySql.Data to MySqlConnector in order to use it.

Thank you for pointing out my mistake. However, the key issue is caused by the different endians when reading in the two languages, regardless of the 2nd parameter. Assuming the binary guid is 0x010203040506..., BIN_TO_UUID will output it as 01020304-0506..., while .net will default to reading it in little endian as 0x04030201, 0x0605, ...
